# what microphone can recording ultrasound (about 40khz)

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, microphone, ultrasound

I want to record ultrasound then their processing signal on raspberry pi but I don't know type of microphone that can interface with raspberry to can measure ultrasound ( I using MA40s4s ultrasonic of Murata to generate waves). Please give me some how can recording ultrasound

Comment: The sensors on all those cheap distance ranging modules should work there if your requirements aren't particular.  You'd need some kind of fast ADC (or one that has the analog bandwidth to understample) that you can interface to the pi.

Comment: @Chris Stratton, please give me some audio card ADC and microphone that can record ultrasound >=40khz.

Comment: Sorry, but "shopping" questions are considered off topic here - talking about how you could build something is allowed, but doesn't sound like it's the most effective solution for your needs.  Unfortunately most off-the-shelf audio ADCs cannot cover those frequencies, as they have low pass filters built in.

Answer (score 1):

try  dual  parts same as emitter for detection but shunted.

Keep switch on during Tx. Add gain as required on 2nd stage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6Dw7t.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The Murata MA40s4 is *called* an "Ultrasonic SENSOR" by Murata. So you have essentially answered your own question. Use another Murata MA40s4 to receive the ultrasonic signal.